# italic function is not working when i integrate it in the main code

Tags: html, css

I have my HTML code and my CSS code and when I integrate them everything works except for the italic and I don't know why; can someone explain?

```
<div id="italic">
    <p >
        <span id="italic">Bears care deeply about family members.
            They will risk their lives and even fight to the death in order
            to save a cub or sibling from danger.
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

and the css is :

```
.subbox {
  border : 1px solid lightgray;
  padding : 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#italic {
    font-style: : italic;
}

.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.removingb {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: should be `font-style: italic;` not `font-style: : italic;`

Comment: Typo. Extra `:`. Would have been picked up if you had used https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: HTML is invalid too. IDs must be **unique** in a page.

Comment: thank you guys and thank you for this tool https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 1):

you need to removed extra colon : from your CSS code

```
#italic {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

or either you can used this tag `<i></i>` for italic

Answer (score 0):

like that you entered something extra in your code.

```
#italic {
font-style: **:** italic;
}
```

You must remove the second : so your code will be right :)